# Align popup menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

**I am created a popup and open at top of the screen **

```
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.llll);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)     context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   changeStatusPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
   changeStatusPopUp.setContentView(layout);
   changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(160);
   changeStatusPopUp.setHeight(229);
   changeStatusPopUp.setFocusable(true);

   int OFFSET_X = -20;
   int OFFSET_Y = 50;

   changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y  + OFFSET_Y);
```

**when i run program and open popup menu on emulator then popup location is perfect**

[image: emulator]

**and when i run on bluestack then open right of the center, It's not perfect **

[image: blue stack]

and when i run on then mobile the hide all menu item please suggest me how to the fix popup location like emulator.

[image: phone]

**my popup xml code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/llll"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/limyprofile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opmyprofile"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:maxHeight="40dip"
        android:maxWidth="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/myprofileimg" />
    <TextView

    android:id="@+id/myprofiletxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
         android:text="My Profile"
         android:textColor="#FF0000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
/>

</LinearLayout>

 <View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/lijobalert"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opjobalert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clickable="true"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:maxHeight="40dip"
       android:maxWidth="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/jobalert4" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/opjobalerttxt"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
         android:textColor="#FF0000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Job Alert" />

</LinearLayout>

     <View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
       android:id="@+id/lisavedjob"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opsavedjob"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clickable="true"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:maxHeight="40dip"
       android:maxWidth="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/sa" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/savedtxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:clickable="true"
         android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Saved Jobs" />

 </LinearLayout>

     <View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <LinearLayout  
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
         android:id="@+id/liback" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clickable="true"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:maxHeight="40dip"
       android:maxWidth="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/back1" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/backtxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
         android:textColor="#FF0000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Back" />

   </LinearLayout>

      <View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/listlogout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/oplogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:maxHeight="40dip"
       android:layout_weight="2"
       android:maxWidth="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/logout" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/logouttxt"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
       android:layout_weight="8"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
         android:textColor="#FF0000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Logout" />

  </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest me how we can open popup at top like emulator for all devices

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
I am really sorry about my bad English.

Comment: On which event you are opening the popup menu ?

Comment: You should check the design guideline first (https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html) and then see if you maybe need a drawer there. As for the popup problem you're experiencing, emulators are often not the best tool for testing your app, you should work on a real phone whenever possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in showAtLocation(), don't you want to specify gravity rather than offset?

Comment: Thanks for answering bro..  how we can use ShowAtLocation(), I am new in android so i don't have idea about that.